# jQuery window size

Tags: jquery, html, css

we're busy writing an portfolio kind of plugin.

We need to know how we can let the script know what the size of the screen is everytime the page loads en after the window is getting resized. At the moment when the user is moving the mouse the window-size is calculated over and over. We only want this when the page is loaded for the first time and after it's resized.

What would be the best solution? Thanks!

```
$(document).on("mousemove", function (event) {
    var mouseposX = event.pageX;
    var mouseposY = event.pageY;
    windowX = $(window).width();
    windowY = $(window).height();
    offsetX = Math.round(-(mouseposX / windowX * (blokjeContainerWidth - windowX)));
    offsetY = Math.round(-(mouseposY / windowY * (blokjeContainerHeight - windowY)));
});
```

This is the link to the example : [portoflio](http://graatieus.nl/mousemove)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `resize` function on the `window` object. Then you can call the function on load using `.resize()`

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
    var mouseposX = event.pageX;
    var mouseposY = event.pageY;
    windowX = $(window).width();
    windowY = $(window).height();
    offsetX = Math.round(-(mouseposX / windowX * (blokjeContainerWidth - windowX)));
    offsetY = Math.round(-(mouseposY / windowY * (blokjeContainerHeight - windowY)));
}).resize();
```

Comment: You could call the resize function right after you bind it to simulate an onLoad event, it would save the duplicate code. `$(window).resize (function () { ... }).resize ();`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding it to the `mousemove` event, just call the calculation on either `$(document).ready()` (after DOM ready) or `$(window).load()` (after resources are loaded).

Then bind your code above to the window `resize` event instead of `mousemove`.  You may also want to look into throttling / debouncing jQuery plugins as the firing of `resize` event is not consistent across different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the info pretty easily with jquery**

```
var ww = $(window).width();//initial width
var wh = $(window).height();//initial height 
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    ww = $(this).width();//new width
    wh = $(this).height();//new height
});
```

So with that, you would just need to change x and y value to this:

```
windowX = ww;
windowY = wh;
```

I added reporting to a fiddle, so you can see the values as they update.

http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/CWhzM/